# moving the location of BCD Store?

Tags: boot, bcd

How do I verify that the BCD store has actually moved?

**I had:**

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=F:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {59d84d8a-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {59d84d8c-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {59d84d8a-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
nx                      OptOut
```

**Then I ran:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:
The operation completed successfully.
```

**Now I have:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=C:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {59d84d8a-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {59d84d8c-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {59d84d8a-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
nx                      OptOut
```

Has the location of the store actually moved? or have I just messed up the settings?

Comment: How to view bootmgr and boot directory- dir /ah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have just changed the reference.

Use [BCDboot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744347(WS.10).aspx) and/or [Bootrec](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) to install/recover the BCD Store.

Answer (score 1):

You can physically copy the BCD store using file copy, or you can export the BCD store to any Windows drive.

If you want to move Windows boot files (it is not enough to move just BCD file) to another partition this is another story.

[How to move Windows 7/8 boot files to another partition.](http://www.boyans.net/MoveWindows7BootFilesToAnotherDrive.html) Again this has only meaning for MBR disks.
On GPT disks and UEFI firmware Windows 7/8 boots always from ESP - EFI System Partition.